# using jquery, how can i select all images inside of a div to change its source

Tags: jquery, image

I have the following div and I know the selector Id of the DIV.

```
<div class="event">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar1.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar2.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar3.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar4.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar5.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar6.png">
</div>
```

I need something to find all images selector inside the div that i have so i can go change the source of the each image to a new image.

Comment: `$('div#idOfDiv  img')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each & http://api.jquery.com/prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to retrieve the image URL:

```
$('.event img').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

if you want to change the image URL then use this:

```
var inc = 1;
$('.event img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','path of image/imagename'+inc+'.imageextension');
  inc++;
});
```

Comment: May i ask why not just set `i` inside `function()`, `then var inc = 1;` is not needed

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes you can ask :) . Just because that index is not always numeric and it can be vary that's why.

Answer (score 3):

You can try children selector and attr callback together.

```js
  $(".event img").attr("src", function() { // or id
      return "Something/" + $(this).attr("src");
 });
   console.log($(".event").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar1.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar2.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar3.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar4.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar5.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar6.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through each element like this:

`i` represent the index of each element, I've added this incase you want something like

`imgurl1`
`imgulr2`
`imgurl3`

and so on

```js
$(".event img").each(function(i, x) {
  $(this).attr("src", "/Content/Images/Icons/NewURL" + (i + 1) + ".png")
  console.log($(this).attr("src"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar1.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar2.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar3.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar4.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar5.png">
  <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar6.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could following code snippet to return list of img elements,

```
$('.event').find('img');
```

Answer (score 1):

change all to same:

```
$(".event>img").attr("src","/New/Image.jpg");
```

change all to something:

```
$(".event>img").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("src",variable);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  array selector For that : `img[0] , img[1]` 
And `.Attr` method `("src","url");` 
Or you can Just give Them class to select the each img !!